# Is graph2dot available in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, ffmpeg

graph2dot is mentioned in `man ffmpeg-filters`, but isn't in the FFmpeg package or its dependencies, including libavfilters6.

I've installed FFmpeg, but get "graph2dot: command not found" when I try to run it.

Is it still in Ubuntu, and if so, where?

Per request:

```
[root@kaga ~]# apt-cache policy ffmpeg  
ffmpeg: 
  Installed: 7:3.3.4-2  
  Candidate: 7:3.3.4-2  
  Version table:  
 *** 7:3.3.4-2 500  
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 Packages  
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Hi sesamemucho. From what I can see, the graph2dot filter should be part of the standard distribution of ffmpeg provided for 17.10. Can you add the output of `apt-cache policy ffmpeg` to your question?

Comment: `graph2dot` is not a filter, but an independent tool included in the FFmpeg source code. It is not provided by the Ubuntu ffmpeg package, but [`graph2dot` is easy to compile](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/21023/1760).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Easy enough to build; are you aware if I can host the binary on my web site if I add a license to the archive? License: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/COPYING.GPLv3

Comment: @andrew.46 Sure. Just include the `COPYING.LGPLv2.1` license (`graph2dot` is LGPLv2.1 or later), the exact version of the source code you used has to be made available somehow (for example an archive on your site for example, or offer to provide it if anyone wants it), and and if any changes are made to the code they must be documented.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Hmmm... I have answered with detailed 'build your own' instructions, if this is not enough I will package...

Comment: @andrew.46 Looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application graph2dot is not available as part of Artful Aardvark's FFmpeg package. However it is pretty straightforward  to build your own copy using the following few steps. (My suspicion is that graph2dot is reasonably FFmpeg-version agnostic but we will use the same *major* version of FFmpeg that comes with Artful, to be sure...)

**1. Compile & install graph2dot:**

Open a Terminal window and run the following single command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential yasm && \
mkdir $HOME/graph2dot_build && cd $HOME/graph2dot_build && \
wget https://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.3.7.tar.gz && \
tar xvf ffmpeg-3.3.7.tar.gz && cd ffmpeg-3.3.7 && \
./configure && make -j 4 && \
make tools/graph2dot && sudo cp -v tools/graph2dot /usr/local/bin
```

**2. Test the installation:**

Now you can test your copy as follows:

```
andrew@illium~$ graph2dot -h
Convert a libavfilter graph to a dot file.
Usage: graph2dot [OPTIONS]

Options:
-i INFILE         set INFILE as input file, stdin if omitted
-o OUTFILE        set OUTFILE as output file, stdout if omitted
-h                print this help
andrew@illium~$
```

This has been tested by me on a fresh Artful Aardvark 17.10 VM and should work perfectly on your system as well.

**3. Clean the build area:**

After testing remove the build directory and its contents:

```
rm -rfv $HOME/graph2dot_build
```

And have a great day :)

**References:**

- [FFmpeg Filters Documentation: graph2dot](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#graph2dot): How to use graph2dot now we have it installed!
- [Video Production Stack Exchange: Installing graph2dot](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21017/ffmpeg-graph2dot-tool/21023#21023): Detailed installation and usage directions.